# How to remove child from UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

It's maybe stupid question but I just cant figure out how to do this. I have a UserControl named "ReportUserControl" and inside of it I have a Grid named "ReportGrid" . I want to remove ReportGrid from ReportUserControl children. I tried this:

```
ReportUserControl control = new ReportUserControl();
control.Children.Remove(...);
```

Problem is that there is no .Children.Remove() option for UserControl. How can i manage this?

**UPDATE**

I want to "send" this grid to another class and use it there. Problem is that when I send the grid and try to use it in another class I get this: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first." so I have to remove it from my UserControl but don't know how.

**ReportUserControl XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFReportTest.ReportUserControl "
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="29.7cm" Width="21cm">

     <Grid Name="ReportGrid">
          ****GridContent***
     </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**ReportClass:**

```
public class ReportingClass
{
   Grid reportGrid;
   public ReportingClass(Grid tempGrid)
   {
       reportGrid = tempGrid;
   }

   public Page SetPageContent()
   {
       Page page = new Page();
       page.Content = reportGrid;
   }      

}
```

**InstanceWindow**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReportUserControl userControl = new ReportUserControl();
        ReportingClass report = new ReportingClass(userControl.ReportGrid);
    }
 }
```

This is not the full code only small part to get idea of what I'm trying to manage. Line "page.Content = reportGrid;" is where the exception happens.

Comment: What does `ReportUserControl` inherit from?

Comment: ReportUserControl : UserControl

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You should use proper DataBinding instead.

Comment: `UserControl` doesn't have a `Children` property, so of course `.Children.Remove` won't do anything. How are you adding `ReportGrid` to it?

Comment: @Stojdza can you show some code?

Comment: Check my update I hope that'll help.

Comment: @Stojdza where you create instance of `ReportingClass` ?

Comment: Forgot to add that part I'll update my code again.

Answer (score 0):

`UserControl` has `Content` property ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

If you want to delete content set null:

```
ReportUserControl control = new ReportUserControl();
control.Content = null;
```

*Example:*

```
public class ReportingClass
{
    ReportUserControl _reportUserControl;
    Grid reportGrid;
    public ReportingClass(ReportUserControl reportUserControl, Grid tempGrid)
    {
        _reportUserControl = reportUserControl;
        reportGrid = tempGrid;
    }

    public Page SetPageContent()
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        // _reportUserControl is the instance of object ReportUserControl where content is reportGrid
        _reportUserControl.Content = null;
        page.Content = reportGrid;
        return page;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReportUserControl userControl = new ReportUserControl();
        ReportingClass report = new ReportingClass(userControl, userControl.Content as Grid);       
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Stojdza check my answer again :)

Answer (score 0):

@Stojdza, in WPF, we generally don't manipulate UI elements in that way. We manipulate *data* elements and declare `DataTemplate`s to define what that data looks like. So in your case, you shouldn't literally move the `Grid`... just move the data and let WPF regenerate your `Grid` wherever you want using the same `DataTemplate`. It will look just the same, but it's a whole lot easier and you'll save yourself all of this trouble.

So, if you're interested in doing this the easy way, first create a class that has all of the properties required in the `UserControl`, let's call it `Data`. Now declare a `DataTemplate` in `Application.Resources` so that you can use it application-wide:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourNamespacePrefix:Data}">
    <!-- Define your Grid here -->
<DataTemplate>
```

Now whenever you want to display your `Grid`, whether in a collection, or individually, you just need to bind a property of type `Data` (or a collection of them) to some form of `ContentControl`:

```
public Data Data { get; set; }
```

...

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Data}" />
```

So rather than trying to copy the `Grid`, you just copy the data to another property of type `Data` and recreate the `Grid` with the single line above. See the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more information on `DataTemplate`s.